# Should I use view to make fixed conditions query?

Tags: mysql, sql

If I want to get current day rows in a table,Which approach below is better than each other:

1. Create a view and add where clause (e.g `where create_time = curdate()`)
2. Create a table, insert rows into it when some rows is inserted into relative table, and at every day 0am, clear all rows in the table by schedule event.

In most cases, I will only get a part of rows in the table but all.MySQL cannot add index to view, so the query performance of approach 2 may be better than approach 1's.

Actually, I want to know if there is cache for view query, by says, I create the view, and then I insert a row into the table which the view is relative to, will MySQL automaticly add the row to cache of the view for next query?

Comment: It depend on how you will use it and how many rows in the table.

Comment: @fifonik it will be less than 10,000 rows

Comment: 10K per day or total? And what about load scenario? With create_time indexed on the table  the index will be used while selecting from view (a fex composite inexes might be needed for real queries). I'd start with view as it is simpler.

Comment: @fifonik sorry, total less than 10,000

Comment: Specifically in regards to MySQL, if you never use a view that will be no bad thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't use

```
where create_time = curdate()
```

because `create_time` sure sounds like it has a time component.  I would use:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.create_time >= curdate();
```

Presumably future dates aren't in the table.

For performance, create an index on `(create_time)`.

Comment: thank you, I will change ```create_time``` to ```create_date```. so I should use view right?

Comment: @wangjun . . . Yes, you should use a view either with the appropriate index or partitioning the table.

Comment: Searches on views in MySQL appear to have no access to their underlying indexes, rendering this advice questionable.

Comment: @Strawberry . . . That depends on the algorithm that is used to define the view.  MySQL prefers the "merge" algorithm, which does allow the optimizer to use indexes for processing the logic.  You can review this in the documentation:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/view-algorithms.html.